# code pulls up an object has no type pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, shader, pyglet, opengl-3

this is the code i know is making the errors

```
    self.scale_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, b"scale")

    self.rotate_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, b"rotate")

    self.scale = pyrr.Matrix44.identity()
    
    self.rot_y = pyrr.Matrix44.identity()

def rotate(self):
    self.scale = pyrr.Matrix44.from_scale(pyrr.Vector3([0.2, 0.2, 1.0])).flatten()
    
    self.rot_y = pyrr.Matrix44.from_y_rotation(time.perf_counter() * 2).flatten
    
    #self.rot_y = [y for x in self.rot_y for y in x]
    c_scale = (GLfloat * len(self.scale))(*self.scale)
    c_rotate_y = (GLfloat * len(self.rot_y))(*self.rot_y)

    glUniformMatrix4fv(self.scale_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, c_scale)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(self.rotate_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, c_rotate_y)
```

the error is

```
   c_rotate_y = (GLfloat * len(self.rot_y))(*self.rot_y)
   TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

i don't know if it is outdated or what. im following a 4 years old tutorial series. let me know if you need anymore information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pyrr - Matrices](https://pyrr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oo_api_matrix.html) are represented by 2 dimensional [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) arrays. To convert the NumPy array to a [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) you have to [`flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) it. The number of elements in the array can be get from the [`size`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) attribute:

```py
self.scale = pyrr.Matrix44.from_scale(pyrr.Vector3([0.2, 0.2, 1.0])).flatten()
self.rot_y = pyrr.Matrix44.from_y_rotation(time.perf_counter() * 2).flatten()

c_scale = (GLfloat * self.scale.size)(*self.scale)
c_rotate_y = (GLfloat * self.rot_y.size)(*self.rot_y)

glUniformMatrix4fv(self.scale_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, c_scale)
glUniformMatrix4fv(self.rotate_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, c_rotate_y)
```

Comment: c_translate = (GLfloat * self.translate.size)(*self.translate)
keeps saying this has no attribute size. it said the same thing when i tried to hand type your sugestion. any idea why

Comment: @AwesomeNoob999 You mean that `(GLfloat * self.scale.size)(*self.scale)` works, but ` (GLfloat * self.translate.size)(*self.translate)` does not work?

Comment: it worked only when i directly copied what u typed

Comment: @AwesomeNoob999 Do you consider `.flatten()`?

Comment: Turns out i had forgotten to put parentheses somewhere